# activate virtual environment for Apache deployment

Tags: apache, flask, deployment, virtualenv

Official docs refer to this script

```
python_home = '/usr/local/envs/myapp1'

activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

But my venv has no file `activate_this.py`. Some other responses to a similar question suggested to *borrow the file from the virtual environment*, but it remains unclear to me. How do I borrow and what does it even mean?
I need to activate my venv to deploy a Flask server with apache.

Comment: Environments created with `python -m venv` lack `activate_this.py`. I don't use `python -m venv`, instead I use `virtualenv`. Install it and give it a try.